# Specify date fomat for sqlalchemy Date column

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, werkzeug

I am working with sqlalchemy and create my initial test database with this small script:

```
with db_session() as session:

    test_object = TestObject(
        start=datetime.strptime("2021-01-06 22:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        ...
    )
    session.add(test_object)
    session.commit()
```

My Model looks like this:

```
class TectObject(Model):
    start = Column(Date, name="start")
    ...
```

I am saving my data in a sqlite database table.
When I query my object using flask, I get a different format back:

```
query = session.query(TestObject).filter(TestObject.id == id)
event = jsonify(query.first().asdict())
--------------- OUTPUT --------------------------------------------
{
 start": "Wed, 06 Jan 2021 22:00:00 GMT"
 ...
 }
```

How do I specify the sqlalchemy Model to only use the format  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the default format produced by [flask/jsonify](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/json/__init__.py#L44), and ultimately from [werkzeug.http.http_date](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/src/werkzeug/http.py#L968).  `print(obj.start)` should show that the default serialisation is to the format that you expect.

Comment: can you try without jsonify and tell us what is the output. just wanted to know?

Comment: Sure, without using jsonify I get an error, saying 
ValueError: Couldn't parse datetime string: '2021-01-06'. @NavaneethaKrishnan

Comment: okay. you want display this in webpage? or want to use with any other func?

Comment: What I originally wanted was a format that is used in the database and not format any date when it is used within a request. Preferably the one I am using in the database.

Comment: The answers to the linked duplicate show how to customise how jsonify formats date objects; you should be able to convert them to handle datetimes by changing the object from `date` to `datetime` where appropriate; `obj.isoformat` should provide the format you want, or you can customise using `datetime.strftime`